# What version of JS / ES do CloudFlare workers use?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

What version of JS/ES do [CloudFlare workers](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cloudflare-workers/) use?

I want to be able to use modern JS like `string.replaceAll()` but haven't been able to find versioning info in the [official docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudflare Workers always uses at least the version of V8 that is current in Google Chrome's stable channel. (Actually, it usually tracks Chrome's beta channel, but that's not guaranteed.)

[This is documented here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/web-standards#javascript-standards) (as @Calculuswhiz noted in their comment).